# Why does Ramda work in this example where native Array.map or Lodash do not?

Tags: ramda.js

In the process of writing an example for [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932502/how-to-add-additional-data-with-data-read-from-a-node-stream-in-read-callback-ha), this question came up:

Why does the native `Array.map` throw an error when used like this:

```
[tmp1, tmp2].map(fs.createReadStream)
  .forEach(stream => stream.pipe(jsonStream));


fs.js:1664
    throw new TypeError('"options" argument must be a string or an object');
    ^

TypeError: "options" argument must be a string or an object
    at new ReadStream (fs.js:1664:11)
    at fs.createReadStream (fs.js:1649:10)
    at Array.map (native)
```

Similarly with lodash… but it works fine with ramda.

```
// Same error:
_.map([tmp1, tmp2], fs.createReadStream)
  .forEach(stream => stream.pipe(jsonStream));

// Works fine:
R.map(fs.createReadStream, [tmp1, tmp2])
  .forEach(stream => stream.pipe(jsonStream));
```

Note, this is the full code from referenced question:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream');

var tmp1 = path.join(__dirname, 'data', 'tmp1.json');
var tmp2 = path.join(__dirname, 'data', 'tmp2.json');

var jsonStream = JSONStream.parse();
jsonStream.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('---\nFrom which file does this data come from?');
  console.log(data);
});

[tmp1, tmp2].map(p => {
  return fs.createReadStream(p);
}).forEach(stream => {
  stream.pipe(jsonStream);
});
```

The second argument of `fs.createReadStream` should be `undefined` no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely due to `Array.prototype.map` and `_.map` passing three arguments to the provided mapping function (the value, the index and the collection), while `R.map` only passes the value.

In your example, `fs.createReadStream` is being given the array index as its second argument where it expects an options object or string instead, causing the `"options" argument must be a string or an object` error. If you want to use `Array.prototype.map` or `_.map` in this way, you'll need to wrap the method call in a function to prevent the extra arguments:

```
[tmp1, tmp2].map(p => fs.createReadStream(p))
```

Comment: Thanks! Knew about the extra args but didn't do 1 + 1 :)